# jQuery filter two table rows (parent and next) with drop down

Tags: jquery

I am trying to filter two rows based on the selected drop down.  I am failing to show the next table row "crackers".

```
$("#filter").change(function () {
$("#thisTable").find("td").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() != $("#filter").val()) 
        $(this).parent().hide();
    else 
        $(this).parent().show();
    if ($("#filter").val() == "ALL") 
        $(this).parent().show();
});});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nope_four/xp7zmpju/

I assume this has been asked and answered before, but I am coming up empty.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can search in `td` that it's parent `tr` has class `.cheese`. When find match then show parent (`tr`) and next one which is `tr` with class `.crackers`. I think you can simplify it to this:

```js
$("#filter").change(function() {
  //change the selector to class cheese children
  $(".cheese td").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() != $("#filter").val()) {
      $(this).parent().hide();
      //hide next tr(which is the one with class cracker)
      //when doesn't match
      $(this).parent().next().hide();
    } else {
      //show next tr(which is the one with class cracker)
      //when match
      $(this).parent().show();
      $(this).parent().next().show();
    }
    if ($("#filter").val() == "ALL") {     
      $(this).parent().show();
      //add this to show all filter to include cracker class too
      $(this).parent().next().show();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filter">
  <option value="ALL">Show All</option>
  <option value="Betty Sue">Betty Sue</option>
  <option value="Jack Jr">Jack Jr</option>
</select>
<table id="thisTable" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cheese">
    <td>ONE</td>
    <td>Betty Sue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="crackers">
    <td colspan="2">Details ONE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cheese">
    <td>TWO</td>
    <td>Jack Jr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="crackers">
    <td colspan="2">Details TWO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cheese">
    <td>THREE</td>
    <td>Betty Sue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="crackers">
    <td colspan="2">Details THREE</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cheese">
    <td>FOUR</td>
    <td>Jack Jr</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="crackers">
    <td colspan="2">Details FOUR</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/aravi_vel/xp7zmpju/12/

You need to loop only `.cheese td`

Also, you need to take care of the `.crackers` row in your code.

Code optimized as well :)

```
$("#filter").change(function () {

    if ($(this).val() == "ALL") {
        $("#thisTable").find("tr").show();
        return true;
    }

    $("#thisTable").find(".cheese td").each(function () {

        var $td = $(this).parent();
        var matched = $(this).text() == $("#filter").val();
        $td.toggle(matched);
        $td.next('.crackers').toggle(matched);

    });
});
```